# Conditions for the possibility of life on a planet

Tags: astrophysics

For an arbitrary planet revolving around a star (assuming there are no other planets or stars around) what are the main properties to determine if that planet has life on it from an astrophysics perspective?

I was thinking the difference between the apastron and periastron is important because if the distance was large then the surface temperature on the planet would be fluctuating (not ideal). I am also wondering about if the period of the planet around the star matters? Any additional information welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parameters might be used to help decide whether or not it's *possible* for life to be on the planet, but will not indicate whether or not it's *likely* that there is life on the planet.  The important parameters probably are temperature and composition.  It is possible sometimes to get a measurement of the absorption spectrum of an exoplanet's atmosphere, and thereby determine whether it has water.  The planet's average distance from its star, and the star's light output, determine the likely temperature of the planet.  As far as we know, (which isn't much!), period of the planet's orbit wouldn't matter.  Temperature fluctuations probably are important if the high-temperature extreme is too high and lasts for too long a time -- but we really don't know what those limits are.  I'd suggest that you do an internet search for "exobiology" and "astrobiology" to learn more.

We really don't know how to detect life on an exoplanet, but it seems possible that the presence of reactive components like oxygen in the atmosphere would be an indication that photosynthesis is going on.  Probably the presence of  organic compounds associated with wildfires would be a strong indication that life is present.

Answer (score 1):

Alright this question is extremly hard to answer because we have little to no info about extraterestial life so take my conclusions with grain of salt.

Assuming life need similar conditions to Earth:
First we need to consider what star is in the system and whats its goldilocks zone. 
Next is day lenght because if its too long there are going to be temperature extremese. 
Atmospher that is cabeble of filtering Uv. 
Water in liquid state.

But there are exeptions (even on Earth) mainly extremophiles (organisms that live as the name suggests in extreme conditions that wouldn't support life). Maybe life doesn't even need water or another liquid to develop but that is a question concerning abiogenesis and I don't feel qualified to speak about that but from what I understand water or other liquids are more likely to develop life.

Lastly I wasn't talking about inteligent or complex life my aswer is focused on the bare minimum of what we consider life which is bacteria.